# How to search for cells in data frame with character *?

Tags: character

I am trying to find rows in which any cell contains the character * (not wild character). I want to drop drop the rows with the specific character * in any cell in that row.

What is the best way to implement it.

Comment: This question needs more detail. I'm not sure if it's safe to assume that this is a database question, but is this for - *just to name a few* - MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle?
You can also add more keywords for people to better understand the question. Please refer to **https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask** for more information.

Comment: Please read "How ask a Question section". Thank you very much